# Допоможіть з пошуком оригіналу перекладеного вислову "непозбувна бентега"

Tags: переклад

Нібито у перекладі роману "Маг" Джона Фаулза зустрічається словосполучення [*непозбувна бентега*](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B0_(%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BC))

Це словосполучення спричинило бурхливі обговорення в мережі. Підкажіть будь ласка, який саме вислів англійською був перекладений як *непозбувна бентега*?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Пошук у Ґуґлі за "непозбувною бентегою" дозволяє [знайти](https://books.google.com.ua/books?hl=ru&id=x_snDQAAQBAJ&q=%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B0#v=snippet&q=%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B0&f=false) уривок, у якому з'являєтья цей вираз.

Відповідний йому уривок з оригіналу звучить так:

> It was not in the least a literary feeling, but an intensely mysterious present and concrete feeling of excitement, of being in a situation where anything still might happen.

Отже, "непозбувна бентега" - це переклад виразу "concrete feeling of excitement".