# Яка етимологія слова "бентежити"?

Tags: етимологія

Звідки пішло слово "бентежити"? [Вікісловник](https://uk.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8) цього не знає. Чи є в українській мові інші слова, що мають цей же корінь, або схоже походження?

Інше питання, наскільки поширеним є слово "бентеження"? Я зустрічала дієслово "бентежити"/"збентежити"/тощо багато разів, але як іменник, здається, це слово не дуже поширене у використанні.

Comment: Після [цього](http://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/73/36) іменник теж дуже поширений :)

Comment: Непозбувна бентега)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Етимологічний словник української мови](http://litopys.org.ua/djvu/etymolog_slovnyk.htm): В 7 т. / АН УРСР. Ін-т мовознавства ім. О. О. Потебні; Редкол. О. С. Мельничук (головний ред.) та ін. — К.: Наук. думка, 1982, том 1, сторінка 168 пише:

> Бентежити – походження остаточно не з’ясоване; пов’язувалося з уг[орським] *bénitás* «розслаблення, калічення, нівечення», *bántás* «образа, кривда, мучення» [угорське `s` читається як `ш`]; можливо пов’язане з *бентег* «послушник», турецьке *bende* «раб, слуга»; в такому разі могло означати «поневолювати» (під час ворожих набігів), порівняйте *бантажити*, *бендюжити*, *бентег*.

В цьому ж томі, сторінка 166:

> Бендюжити – «ганьбити, зневажати» – очевидно результат видозміни форми *бентежити* під впливом *бендюга*, *бендюх*, і, можливо, словацького дієслова *bandečit'* «лаятися».

«Бантажити», сторінка 135:

[image]

Отже, існує ціле сімейство слів, корінь яких містить приголосні `б-(н)-т-г/ж`, походження цих слів достеменно не відоме, але вони мають спільні неґативні конотації та скоріш за все вплинули одне на одне.